# probem in create database name by automaticly in mongodb with variable in python3

Tags: python, database, mongodb, network-programming

I want the uuid of each system as the database name for this system to be registered in the central database so that the representative of each system does not need to enter its database name and through the uuid can easily get  database name.
The original  database is MongoDB

All systems are connected to the original database via the special representative of each system and create their own database

All of these have been implemented in Python 3

example :

```
from pymongo import Connection 
connection = Connection() 
db = connection['test-database']
collection = db['test-collection']
```

Here we can not use the variable for uuid as the database name and we need to manually set it up.

codes of server:

```
import os 
import psutil 
import socket 
import db_conn 
import pymongo
from bson.json_util import loads 
import json 
import threading 
import coms 
import time from pymongo 
import MongoClient import get_status_ports 
import port_scanner 

def main():
   db_con = db_conn.db_connection()
   connection = db_con.connections()
   ob_coms = coms.lis_main()
   ob_listen_port = port_scanner.listen_port_sca()
   port_status = get_status_ports.Spetial_Agent()
   db = connection.main_db_192_168_1_4  # Here we have to use the variable  for the database name so that we can set the uuid system - but the variable does not accept it. 
   list_bad = ["python","firefox"]
   port_num = 2882
   status = "listen"
   pid = []
   if ob_listen_port.special_port_scanner(port_num, status) is None:
      conn_sock = ob_coms.port_listen()
      conn, address = conn_sock.accept()
   #if (conn) or (conn is None):
   while True:
      content = db.all_result.find_one(sort=[('date', -1)])
      dict_key = content["result_back"].keys()
      for in_content in dict_key:
          if content["result_back"][in_content]["proc_name"] in list_bad:
              if content["result_back"][in_content]["pid_conn_back"] in pid:
                  pass
              else:
                  pid.append(content["result_back"][in_content]["pid_conn_back"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```